# Azure CDN rules engine remove .html extension

Tags: regex, azure, azure-cdn

I am running a static website on Azure Blob and using CDN premium. I am trying to get all my pages to drop the .html extension in the  URLs.

I have read many guides on how to remove the .html extension on via regex but I can't get it working for all pages. All the guides I can find online only seem to work on the index.html and the image the link to always shows a `/` in the source which they dont write in the descriptions like with [Azure CDN rules engine to rewrite default document and remove .html extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368829/azure-cdn-rules-engine-to-rewrite-default-document-and-remove-html-extension)

```
rule IF Always
Feature
URL Rewrite - source ((?:[^\?]*/)?)($|\?.*) destination $1index.html$2
URL Rewrite - source ((?:[^\?]*/)?[^\?/.]+)($|\?.*) destination $1.html$2
```

Comment: Proper capitalization / clean-up.